# Can any one tell me what is happening in the code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, boolean

```js
const items = [
    { name: 'Bike', price: 100 },
    { name: 'TV', price: 200 },
    { name: 'Album', price: 10 },
    { name: 'Book', price: 5 },
    { name: 'Phone', price: 2000 },
    { name: 'Keyboard', price: 50 },
    { name: 'Mouse', price: 500 },
    { name: 'Computer', price: 30 },
]

const foundItem = Boolean(items.length) && items.filter(item => item.price === 10)

console.log(foundItem)
```

I am facing difficulty in understanding the code above.Can anyone tell me What happening in the above code?

Comment: You are probably referring to the bool expression containing the `&&`. It's evaluated with a "short circuit" rule. The value of the && expression is the first false-like value found when evaluating operands left to right, or, if the operands are truthy, the value of last operand.

Comment: thnx @danh, it helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the foundItem is `{ name: 'Album', price: 10 }`.

The logic is to filter out all the item's which price is equal to `10` while the array length of `items` has at least 1 item.

And printing it in the console.

Comment: what is happening in the following line?                                                                                  const foundItem = Boolean(items.length) && items.filter(item => item.price === 10)                                                                      what is boolean(items.length)&& doing here

Comment: It will filter the items with price 10.

The first part is checking whether the `items.length > 1` or not. `Boolean(0)` will be false and `Boolean(0<1)` will be `true`.

If the length is greater than 0, filtering items with the price of 10.

In my opinion, you could refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array for better understanding about the array functions.

Comment: i am still not able to understand why boolean(items.length) && is used

Comment: can you tell me in any other way?

Comment: items.length is 8but what is meant by boolean(items.length) ? is it meant boolean(8)?

Answer (score 1):

Boolean(item.length) says: if item has at least one item.

item.filter(item => item.price === 10) says: return all items that price is equal 10. filter is an array method that return the items that match the condition you define.

Comment: thnx sir , it helped me

Answer (score 0):

Please tell us what part of this you don't understand. The Boolean constructor, the `&&` shorthand operator, or the `filter` method?

`const foundItem = Boolean(items.length) && items.filter(item => item.price === 10)`

is somewhat equivalent to:

```
let foundItem;
if (!items.length) {
  foundItem = false;
} else {
  foundItem = items.filter(item => item.price === 10);
}
```

For how to use `Array.prototype.filter`, refer to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

`const array2 = array1.filter(method)`

This returns a new array (`array2`) with all elements of `array1` that passes the "test" defined by the function `method`.

Comment: dear @Jasmonate, I am facing difficulty in understanding Boolean constructor and the && shorthand operator

Comment: thnx @jasmonate , it helped me

Answer (score 0):

```
if(items.length){ // checking that array is empty or not
   for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){ // looping
     if(items[i].price === 10){ // checking all items price 10 not not
      foundItem.push( items[i]); // store 
   }
  }
 }
```

hope this code of snippets will help u to understand.

Comment: thnx @imh1j41 , it helped me